# Convert integer to string and use each character

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, integer

How is an integer converted to a string in objective c and how is each character of the string reached?

The equivalent to the java charAt() method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", 36];
[myString characterAtIndex:0]; //"3"
[myString characterAtIndex:1]; //"6"
```

**Update**: Note that `characterAtIndex` returns a unichar not a c char. Thanks @Chuck.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that `characterAtIndex:` returns a unichar, not a normal C char.